# ListView's Items over another item

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, transparent

I'm working with Xamarin Forms and I asking myself if it's possible to make a list, where each item have margin/padding to be able to see through the parent list. It's hard to explain, so let see my example:

[image]

If we take a look at this image, the list is transparent, however, children aren't transparent so  everything is fine.

So, is it possible to make? if yes, how can I superpose the list over my map? I saw some examples but they doesn't match with what I want to make.

The final idea is like, I have a button and then, when I press it, my scrollable listview would appears onto the map (RelativeLayout -> visibility true || or something like that). I am not sure to know how to achieve it...

Also, I'm working with XAML and I was asking myself another thing, does I have to put the list over my map like that:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap">
      <!-- the layout with the list or only the list, i don't know-->
    </local:CustomMap>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```

Or it's better  to work with another way?

Comment: It seems like an AbsoluteLayout might be of use here?

Comment: It seems logic, I'm working on it ;)